# Making quick calculations on subsets with R

Tags: r, subset

and thanks to all in advance.

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(123)

    data <- data.frame (name=LETTERS[sample(1:26, 500, replace=T)],present=sample(0:1,500,replace = T))
```

And I want to quickly calculate the percentage of present observations (1's) for each letter. I can do it manually, but I believe there is an easier way to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
A <- filter(data, name=="A" & present==1)
A2 <- filter(data, name=="A")
data$Percentage[data$name=="A"] <- nrow(A)/nrow(A2)
```

And so on until I arrive to "Z".

Can I make this task automatically without having to change the values of the "name" colum manually?

Best regards,

Comment: You may need `prop.table(table(data))[,1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `prop.table` with `table` to get the proportion

```
prop.table(table(data), 1)[,2]
```

To add it as a column, we can expand it by matching with the 'names'

```
data$Percentage <- prop.table(table(data), 1)[,2][as.character(data$name)]
```

Or as @Lars Lau Raket suggested, we don't need to convert to `character`

```
prop.table(table(data), 1)[,2][data$name]
```

---

If we need to create a column

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(name) %>%
     mutate(Percentage = mean(present==1))
```

Comment: `pt <- prop.table(table(data), 1)[,2];
data$pt <- pt[data$name]`